# What is the difference between oracle 10 express and enterprise manager 10g?

Tags: oracle

What is the difference between Oracle 10 Express and Enterprise Manager 10g?

Which Enterprise Manager 10g V should i download? 1,2,3,4 or 5v?

Comment: Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you mean Oracle 10g express edition, that is a free version of the Oracle database that supports limited amounts of hardware.  You are limited to 4 GB of user data (that limit is increased to 11 GB in Oracle 11g express edition), 1 GB of RAM, and 1 processor but it's all free.  Oracle competes with the other free editions of other database vendors like Microsoft.  Be aware that Oracle offers many products with the word "express" in the title-- Oracle Express is an old OLAP product, Oracle Application Express (APEX) is a framework for developing web applications in PL/SQL, the express edition of the 10g or 11g Oracle database are databasess, etc.

Enterprise Manager, on the other hand, is a tool that allows DBAs to monitor many different servers (database servers, application servers, etc.).  Non-express versions of Oracle come with a standalone version of Enterprise Manager that allows you to manage that one database.  The Enterprise Manager downloads are generally the "grid control" versions that allow for more centralized management.

Comment: thx for help could you tell me please what release should i download? enterprise manger 10.5 or 10.4 or what?

Comment: here is the good tutorial for oracle 10 and oracle 10 _ php or .net http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/tutorial/DBXETutorial/index.htm